# How to get related fields (foreign key) in Yesod?

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod, persistent, hamlet

I've defined the following models in  Yesod application:

```
CvCategory
    title Text
    order Int
    UniqueCvCategory title

CvItem
    category CvCategoryId
    title Text
    fromYear Int
    toYear Int Maybe
    description Text Maybe
    UniqueCvItem title
```

I have the following query in a handler:

```
cvcategories <- selectList [] [] --all cv categories
```

In my hamlet template, I'd like to do something like:

```
<ul>
$forall cvcategory <- cvcategories
    <li>$#{cvCategoryTitle cvcategory}
         $forall cvitem <- cvcategory --how?
         <li>#{cvItemTitle cvitem}
```

In Django, you can easily define a `related_name`, and then use this to easily access all 'child objects'. Is this possible in Yesod too? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query, something like

```
do
  cvcategories <- selectList [] [] --all cv categories
  forM cvcategories $ \cat -> do -- for each category
    cvitems <- selectList [CvCategoryId .== entityKey cat] -- all items belonging to it
    return (cat, cvitems) -- return tuple of category and its items
```

And then your Hamlet would look like

```
<ul>
$forall (cvcategory, cvitems) <- cvcategories
    <li>$#{cvCategoryTitle cvcategory}
         $forall cvitem <- items
         <li>#{cvItemTitle cvitem}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Isn't there a more elegant way though, like how you'd define it in Django (with a related_name that you can use directly in your template)?

Comment: What's unelegant there? A query should define what you fetch from the database. From my POV, that `related_name` thing of Django blurs the border between business logic and persistence layer. But maybe I just missing something, have 0 experience with Django.

Comment: Convenient may have been a better term. In a sense, you're most certainly right, though this is such a common pattern that it's slightly cumbersome to explicitly write a query every time you need to do it.